# Router claims it is connected but devices don't get internet

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, connection, internet-connection

So my router on it's web ui claims it has an IP and an internet connection, but no device connected to the router gets the connection.
When I try to plug my PC straight to the wall (bypass my router) it gets the 169.254.x.x error and no connection.

What should I do?

Comment: *my router on it's web ui claims it has an IP and an internet connection* What WAN IP/mask/gateway/DNS is set? does this settings are static (you set them manually according to ISP info)? does router really may access any internet node (try to ping 8.8.8.8, for example)? Maybe the router simply reports that the physical connection is established? *When I try to plug my PC straight to the wall (bypass my router) it gets the 169.254.x.x* None DHCP answers to it... so APIPA is used.

Comment: Your devices are not receiving an IP from the DNS/DHCP server on the router, as any `169.x.x.x` address is indicative of no connection to a router since it's only assigned when a device fails to be assigned an IP from a router.  Either you've **(1)** misconfigured the LAN subnet on the router or have misconfigured the DHCP server; **(2)** you're not correctly connecting the devices to the router; **(3)** there's an issue with the devices' network connections; or **(4)** there's an issue with the local DNS and DHCP server on the router.  Please see router's documentation or reset it to default.

Comment: @jw0914 the devices do get an IP when connected to the router, they don't when connected straight to the wall

Comment: @Jokru I misread your question.  Reset the router to its factory defaults or consult the manufacturer's support page.  Just an FYI, never connect a device directly to a modem, as modems have no firewall and are not intended to be directly connected to a device - they are **always** meant to be connected to a router.  A modem cannot be hot-swapped, which is why you received a link-local IP [`169.x.x.x`], as modems can only be "programmed" with one MAC from a device at a time and must be hard reset (unplugged for >5min) before a new MAC from a new device will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, don't bypass your router. The router has a single network connection(usually labeled WAN) and that should be connected to (in your case) the wall.
The other connections on the router(usually labeled LAN) is where you should connect your PC.

Since we don't know exactly what router you have it is best to start from a known state. All home routers have a push button located in the back(sometimes located on the bottom) that resets the router to the "Default factory Settings". This button might be positioned behind a small pin hole, so you may need a paper clip to poke through the pin hole to press the button. Whatever your case may be, with the router booted up, I suggest that you press and hold this button for 30 seconds or more. Release the button and then allow time for the router to reboot. The router will then have all of the settings that the factory recommends, and any changes that someone may have made before will be cleared. Next, hook up you computer to the router (LAN) and reboot your computer. In most cases, you will have internet access restored to your PC.

Answer (score 0):

A router is exactly that. It routes traffic on certain sets of pre-defined rules. 
One of these rules could be restricting internet access to the Local Area Network (Wireless or Fixed LAN). If it is showing a connection to the Wide Area Network (WAN - eg connection to ISP) then it is unlikely the issue is between the router and your ISP.

In your router settings, you need to ensure that DHCP is enabled and also that you have your network connection settings configured for this on your end device (laptop, phone, etc.)
In your router LAN settings, check that it has been configured to allow access.
Without knowing more, it's difficult to help further.
If this doesn't help, please answer the following:

1. What is the make/model of the router
2. Has this ever worked?
3. What is the connection in the wall?

Comment: Please add _"If this doesn't help..." and everything that follows to a comment under the OP's question

Comment: Only one I know the answer to is 2: yes up until 2 days ago when it just stopped